# Golf 4 water loss

Tags: vw, golf, water-leak

Hello I have a Golf 4 and the I had to refill the box of water every month and this is not a normal case cuz the car shouldnt use the water , so i change the box and now it gets empty every 2 days ... Is the problem with the way i changed it or there is a leak of water somewhere and i have to search where it is cz i think i didnt vent it after replacing the new one ... Anyone could help ? And sry about my english

Comment: What "box" is it that you changed? Are you talking about the surge tank? What year of Golf do you have? Which engine? How many miles?

Comment: The box is the plastic one that you fill it water ... Its the only thing in the car that contains water ... Its a golf 2001 2.0 engine and about 70000 miles

Comment: [Is this the part you changed?](http://www.rockauto.com/info/154/Z49028photo%20primary__ra_p.jpg) (coolant recovery tank) or [does it look like this?](http://www.rockauto.com/info/69/VW1288113__ra_p.jpg) (washer reservoir)